# Cross origin blocked in HTML5 Audio element with AudioContext API Safari?

Tags: javascript, macos, safari, audiocontext, cross-origin-read-blocking

When using AudioContext API cross domain requests are blocked.

To get around this you init the audio element like so :

```
<audio crossorigin="anonymous"></audio>
```

This works fine in FF & Chrome but not in Safari on OSX?

Does Safari still not support the `crossorigin` tag in HTML5 media elements?

If not are there any work arounds?

I'm using it to stream audio via https so loading the object by XHR isn't suitable.